# PHP/MySQL Performance Testing with Just PHP

Tags: php, mysql, performance, apache2, webserver

I'm trying to diagnose a server where the website is loading very slowly, but unfortunately my client has only provided me with FTP access.

I've got FTP access so I can upload PHP scripts, but can't set up any other server side tools.

I have access to phpMyAdmin, but not direct access to the MySQL server.  It is also unfortunately a Windows server (and we've been a Linux shop for over a decade now).

So, if I wan to evaluate MySQL & disk speed performance through PHP on a generic server, what is the best way to do this?

There are already tools like:
  https://github.com/raphaelm/php-benchmark or https://github.com/InfinitySoft/php-benchmark

But I'm surprised there isn't something that someone has already set up & configured to just run through and do some basic testing of a server's responsiveness.

Every time we evaluate a new server environment it's handy to be able to compare it to an existing one quickly to see if there are any anomalies.  I guess I'd just hoped that someone else had written up a script to do this already.  I know I have, but that was before Github when there was a handy place to post scraps of code like this.

Comment: Maybe this question should be put on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com). Having access only to FTP and phpMyAdmin it is gonna be a tough task.

Comment: Ok, I re-posted it on ServerFault. Wish I could just move it, but not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already done this, but just in case... If I were in your shoes, the first thing I'd be looking at are the indexes on the mysql tables and the queries in the application. I've seen some sites get huge speed boosts just by fixing a join or adding a missing index.

Don't forget to check the code for performance issues or calls to sleep(). If you haven't yet, it may be helpful to get the code running locally so you can run it through xdebug.

Comment: This is definitely a good idea, and one I used to do a lot more of before I started working with Drupal.  Definitely reviews to the SQL would make improvements (and we haven't done that).

However, we know it works fine in a substantially less powerful machine.  Using Drupal's Devel module I could also review the microseconds for DB queries and they were less than 1% of the page load times.

I'm not sure if it's a filesystem problem or just how PHP's been configured, but I need to be able to do some basic tests to find the bottleneck.

Comment: In that case, I'd start by running a `phpinfo()` script on both servers running the code base. Then run them through diff to see what's different in the php configuration on the two machines, might point you in the right direction. Since you're using Drupal, are there any Drupal modules for checking server health?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the phpinfo() results wouldn't tell us much.  It's certainly an idea and something we reviewed on the slow server.

It's benchmarks like how fast can it write, modify, & delete 10k sample files.  Similar for DB queries.  Might be stuff to assess the speed of the RAM.  Not sure.